# OpenGL Not Detecting Link Errors (OR Wrong Triggers?)

Tags: c++, opengl, error-handling, linker, shader

I have written a little macro to detect shader compiler erros, and shader program link errors:

```
        #define OPEN_GL_FUN_SHADER_DEBUG_STATUS_REPORTER_SHADER_UTILITIES_CPP( WHAT_TO_GET, STATUS, DEBUG_DATA, DEBUG_STATUS, ID, FUNCTION_NAME, EXTRA ) \
            if( DEBUG_STATUS == true ) \
            { \
                glGet##WHAT_TO_GET##iv( ID, STATUS, ( &DEBUG_DATA.status ) ); \
                if( DEBUG_DATA.status == GL_FALSE ) \
                { \
                    GLint logLength; \
                    glGet##WHAT_TO_GET##iv( ID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, ( &logLength ) ); \
                    std::vector< GLchar > log( logLength ); \
                    glGet##WHAT_TO_GET##InfoLog( ID, logLength, ( &logLength ), ( &log[ 0 ] ) ); \
                    auto shaderLog = log.data(); \
                    if( ( !( typeid( GLchar ) == typeid( char ) ) ) == true ) { \
                        std::cerr << "Warning::" \
                                FUNCTION_NAME \
                                "::GLchar and char are " \
                                "not of the same type, this could cause difficulty when error reporting logging.\n"; \
                    } \
                    DEBUG_DATA.errorMessage = std::string{ log.data() }; \
                    DEBUG_DATA.logLength = logLength; \
                    DEBUG_DATA.shaderId = ID; \
                    EXTRA \
                } \
            }
```

It works find for shaders, but I have no idea why it wont detect linker errors, I have tried changing it around a bit, but I am not sure why it wont detect the errors, for example, I tried to link a shader with a compiler error, and it linked with no problem, I also tried enter a non - shader id number into `glAttachShader` and it also linked successfully. That's all I can really think of to do in order to practically trigger a linker error, do I have the triggers wrong? Or is something wrong with my code?

EDIT:

The use of the macro was asked for:

```
        /*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!---------------------------------------------!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        Relevant use (there are some default parameters in the header, but they are all set to true.
        !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!---------------------------------------------!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/
    ShaderDebugInformation LinkProgram( GLuint programId, std::vector< ShaderObjectCode > shadersToLink, bool debug, 
            bool deleteShadersOnFailure, bool deleteProgramOnFailure )
    {
        for( const auto& currentShader : shadersToLink )
            glAttachShader( programId, currentShader.objectCodeId );
        glLinkProgram( programId );
        ShaderDebugInformation debugData;
        OPEN_GL_FUN_SHADER_DEBUG_STATUS_REPORTER_SHADER_UTILITIES_CPP( Program, GL_LINK_STATUS, debugData, 
                debug, programId, "LinkProgram( GLuint, std::vector< ShaderObjectCode >[, bool ] )", 
                if( deleteShadersOnFailure == true ) {
                    for( const auto& currentShader : shadersToLink )
                        DeleteShader( currentShader.objectCodeId );
                }
                if( deleteProgramOnFailure == true )
                    DeleteProgram( programId );
                )
        return debugData;
    }
    //Relevant use continued.//
    void LinkProgram( ShaderProgram& programToLink, bool debug, 
            bool deleteShadersOnFailure, bool deleteProgramOnFailure )
    {
        programToLink.debugData = LinkProgram( 
                programToLink.shaderProgramId, programToLink.objectSources, debug, 
                deleteShadersOnFailure, deleteProgramOnFailure );
        if( debug == true && programToLink.debugData.status != GL_FALSE )
        {
            const auto& objectCodeSources = programToLink.objectSources;
            for( const auto& currentShader : objectCodeSources ) 
                glDetachShader( programToLink.shaderProgramId, currentShader.objectCodeId );
        }
    }
    //Irrelevant use.//
    ShaderObjectCode CreateShaderObjectCode( ShaderSource shaderSource, bool debug, bool deleteShaderOnFailure )
    {
        ShaderObjectCode objectCode;
        objectCode.objectCodeId = CompileShader( shaderSource );
        OPEN_GL_FUN_SHADER_DEBUG_STATUS_REPORTER_SHADER_UTILITIES_CPP( Shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, objectCode.debugData, 
                debug, objectCode.objectCodeId, "CreateShaderObjectCode( ShaderSource[, bool ] )", 
                if( deleteShaderOnFailure == true )
                    DeleteShader( objectCode.objectCodeId ); )
        return objectCode;
    }
    //Data structures.//
    struct ShaderDebugInformation
    {
        std::string errorMessage;
        GLuint logLength, shaderId;
        GLint status;
    };

    struct ShaderSource {
        GLenum shaderType;
        std::string shaderSource;
    };

    struct ShaderObjectCode {
        ShaderDebugInformation debugData;
        GLuint objectCodeId;
    };

    struct ShaderProgram
    {
        GLuint shaderProgramId;
        ShaderDebugInformation debugData;
        std::vector< ShaderSource > sourceCode;
        std::vector< ShaderObjectCode > objectSources;
        bool linked;
    };
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a macro? It would be a lot easier to debug as a function. You could just step through it and see what's going wrong. There are only 2 possible values for `WHAT_TO_GET` - `Shader` and `Program`, so why not just pass in an enum for which you want? You could still wrap it in a much simpler macro that supplied the function name.

Comment: @user1118321 I could do a function, but I would have to write `glGetProgramiv` and `glGetShaderiv` (and the same with `glGetXYZInfo`), however I do wrap the macro into a simpler function.

Comment: Can you show how you invoke the macro? Just seeing the macro code alone is not enough without knowing the values of the macro arguments that will be substituted.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I will eddit the question

Comment: Hmm, looks like you're passing in the right arguments. And I figure `debug` is passed in as `true`? You would have a much easier time debugging this if it was not a macro. With what you have, I would probably add some debug logging to confirm that it's going where you think it is, and has the right values. Depending on your system/compiler, there are sometimes also compiler options that let you see the code after preprocessing.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I did do a little logging, it does look like most of the stuff goes where I think it does. However it does not look like the second if `if( DEBUG_DATA.status == GL_FALSE )` is getting passed when linking (with an error case), but I can see in the later output that `status` is `1` or `GL_TRUE`. Unfortunatly I dont have many tools atm, Im on linux (still looking for an nice ide or debugger after windows died :( ).